# C# WPF MVVM, attached behavior to update mainwindow datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attachedbehaviors

In short: is it correct in MVVM pattern to access main window datacontext and update it through behavior class?

long: I'm trying to learn WPF MVVM and make app where one of the functionalities is canvas with draggable ellipses. I found few examples of behaviors that could provide this functionality but they relied on TranslateTransform and this was not the solution I wanted. I want to extract the ellipse coordinates for furhter use.
I also use ItemsControl to display canvas and related items which made impossible to use Canvas.SetTop() command.

After several tries I found a working solution but I’m not sure if this is correct according to MVVM pattern. And if this is the simplest way to achieve the goal… I take up coding as a hobby
if I made some concept mistakes please let me know.

Short app description:

- On app startup the instance of TestWindow2VM class is crated and assigned to main window as datacontext
- TestWindow2VM class contains  ObservableCollection which contains EllipseVM class.
- EllipseVM class holds X,Y coordinates and some other data (brushes etc).
- In XAML in ItemsControl the binding of ItemsSource is set to my  ObservableCollection. In ItemsControl Datatemplate I bind ellipse properties to data stored in EllipseVM class and also add reference to my behavior class
- in ItemsControl ItemContainerStyle canvas top and left properties are bound to my  ObservableCollection
- when ellipse is clicked my behavior class access the datacontext, finds the instance of EllipseVM class and changes X and Y coordinates basing on mouse cursor position relative to canvas.

Code below:

behavior:

```
public class CanvasDragBehavior
    {
        private Point _mouseCurrentPos;
        private Point _mouseStartOffset;        

        private bool _dragged;
        private static CanvasDragBehavior _dragBehavior = new CanvasDragBehavior();
        public static CanvasDragBehavior dragBehavior
        {
            get { return _dragBehavior; }
            set { _dragBehavior = value; }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CanBeDragged",
          typeof(bool), typeof(DragBehavior),
          new PropertyMetadata(false, OnDragChanged));

        public static bool GetCanBeDragged(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDragProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCanBeDragged(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnDragChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = (UIElement)sender;
            var isDrag = (bool)(e.NewValue);

            dragBehavior = new CanvasDragBehavior();

            if (isDrag)
            {
                element.MouseLeftButtonDown += dragBehavior.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
                element.MouseLeftButtonUp += dragBehavior.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
                element.MouseMove += dragBehavior.ElementOnMouseMove;
            }
            else
            {
                element.MouseLeftButtonDown -= dragBehavior.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
                element.MouseLeftButtonUp -= dragBehavior.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
                element.MouseMove -= dragBehavior.ElementOnMouseMove;
            }
        }

        private void ElementOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_dragged) return;

            Canvas canvas = Extension.FindAncestor<Canvas>(((FrameworkElement)sender));
  
            if (canvas != null)
            {
                _mouseCurrentPos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
                FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
                if (fe.DataContext.GetType() == typeof(EllipseVM))
                {
// EllipseVM class contains X and Y coordinates that are used in ItemsControl to display the ellipse
                    EllipseVM ellipseVM = (EllipseVM)fe.DataContext;
                    double positionLeft = _mouseCurrentPos.X - _mouseStartOffset.X;
                    double positionTop = _mouseCurrentPos.Y -  _mouseStartOffset.Y;

                    #region canvas border check
                    if (positionLeft < 0)  positionLeft = 0; 
                    if (positionTop < 0)  positionTop = 0;
                    if (positionLeft > canvas.ActualWidth)  positionLeft = canvas.ActualWidth-fe.Width;
                    if (positionTop > canvas.ActualHeight) positionTop = canvas.ActualHeight-fe.Height;
                    #endregion
                    ellipseVM.left = positionLeft;
                    ellipseVM.top = positionTop;                    
                }
            }    
        }

        private void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

                _mouseStartOffset = e.GetPosition((FrameworkElement)sender);

                _dragged = true;
                ((UIElement)sender).CaptureMouse();

        }

        private void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _dragged = false;
            ((UIElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();

        }
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding scrollViewElements}"  >
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                     <!--some other data templates here-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:EllipseVM}" >
                        <Ellipse Width="{Binding width}" 
                                 Height="{Binding height}"
                                 Fill="{Binding fillBrush}" 
                                 Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"
                                 behaviors:CanvasDragBehavior.CanBeDragged="True"
                                 />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas  Background="Transparent" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">                 
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding top}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding left}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM distinct 3 kinds of object:

- View
- VModel
- Model

The property of the view should be bound to the VModel, you try correctly to bind the view with EllipseVM, like a real Expert!
The issue on your project is that you have not a single View bound to a single VM, but you want an infinite number of VModels.

I will enumerate below some points of reflection:

- I would like to challenge the fact that you register on different drag events:
  element.MouseLeftButtonDown

you should register only when objects are created or destroyed.

- CanvasDragBehavior : why do you implement a singleton like pattern with a static public property (without private constructor) ?
- Avoid registering properties via string like "CanBeDragged" find a way to define and use interfaces eg IMoveFeature{bool IsDraggable}

Comment: If I understand you correctly then by accessing datacontext from my behavior class I make another viewmodel? I thought that something is not right with this approach. So what is the correct way to make a change in my observable collection in my viewmodel? I saw a solution where viewmodel and behavior were connected by common interface and this interface was owner of attached property. Behavior triggered method in viewmodel class. Is this what you mean by using interfaces like IMoveFeature?

Comment: yes, you create another view model. In fact i do not like the name 'viewModel' each shape should have a model, and your datacontext which is referenced by the view should hold the collection of shape models.

Comment: Regarding the lack of private constructor - I followed one of the examples that I found. I understand that correct implementation should be like: private field: `private static CanvasDragBehavior _instance; `
constructor: `private CanvasDragBehavior(){} `
public property: `public static CanvasDragBehavior {get ... //create instance if private field is null}`

Comment: I don't get what you mean by registering only when objects are created or destroyed. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: i mean ensure that you do not register the same event handler more than once on the target object otherwise you will be trigerred several times per object

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complicated and has some errors.
For example the static instance property of the `CanvasDragBehavior` is not required. It looks like you confused something here.

To position the element on the `Canvas` simply use the attached properties [`Canvas.Top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas.top?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and `Canvas.Left`.

Prefer the tunneling version of input events, prefixed with *Preview*. For example listen to `PreviewMouseMove` instead of `MouseMove`.

Another important fix is to use the [`WeakEventManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.weakeventmanager-2?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to subscribe to the events of the attached elements. Otherwise you create a potential memory leak (depending on the lifetime of the event publisher and event listener). Always remember to follow the following pattern to avoid such memory leaks: when you subscribe to events, ensure that you will always unsubscribe too. If you have no control over the object lifetime, always follow the [Weak Event pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and use the `WeakEventManager` to observe events.
In your case: when an item is removed from the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, your behavior won't be able to detect this change in order to unsubscribe from the corresponding events.
The risk of a memory leak in your context is not high, but better be safe than sorry and stick to the safety pattern.

When implementing a control or behavior, try to avoid tight coupling to data types and implementation details. Make the control or behavior as generic as possible. For this reason, your behavior should not know about the `DataContext` and what type of elements are dragged. This way you can simply extend your code or reuse the behavior for example to allow to drag a `Rectangle` too. Right now, your code only works with a `Ellipse` or `EllipseVM`.

Usually, you don't need the position data in your view model. If it's pure UI drag&Drop the coordinates are part of the view only. In this case you would prefer to attach the behavior to the item container instead of attaching it to the elements of the `DataTemplate`: you don't want to drag the data model. You want to drag the item container.
If you still need the coordinates in your model, you would setup a binding in the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` like in the example below (the `DataContext` of the item container `Style` is always the data item, which is of type `EllipseVM` in your case).

The simplified and improved version that targets dragging the item container rather than the data model could look as follows. Note that the following behavior is implemented by only using the `UIElement` type for the dragged object. The actual type of the element or the data model is not required at all. This way it will work with every shape or control (not only `Ellipse`). You can even drag a `Button` or whatever is defined in the `DataTemplate`. The `DataContext` can be any type.

```cs
public class CanvasDragBehavior
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsDragEnabled",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(CanvasDragBehavior),
    new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsDragEnabledChanged));

  public static bool GetIsDragEnabled(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDragEnabledProperty);
  public static void SetIsDragEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(IsDragEnabledProperty, value);

  private static Point DragStartPosition { get; set; }
  private static ConditionalWeakTable<UIElement, FrameworkElement> ItemToItemHostMap { get; } = new ConditionalWeakTable<UIElement, FrameworkElement>();

  private static void OnIsDragEnabledChanged(object attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (attachingElement is not UIElement uiElement)
    {
      return;
    }

    var isEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (isEnabled)
    {
      WeakEventManager<UIElement, MouseButtonEventArgs>.AddHandler(uiElement, nameof(uiElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown), OnDraggablePreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
      WeakEventManager<UIElement, MouseEventArgs>.AddHandler(uiElement, nameof(uiElement.PreviewMouseMove), OnDraggablePreviewMouseMove);
      WeakEventManager<UIElement, MouseButtonEventArgs>.AddHandler(uiElement, nameof(uiElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp), OnDraggablePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp);
    }
    else
    {
      WeakEventManager<UIElement, MouseButtonEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(uiElement, nameof(uiElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown), OnDraggablePreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
      WeakEventManager<UIElement, MouseEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(uiElement, nameof(uiElement.PreviewMouseMove), OnDraggablePreviewMouseMove);
      WeakEventManager<UIElement, MouseButtonEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(uiElement, nameof(uiElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp), OnDraggablePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp);
    }
  }

  private static void OnDraggablePreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
    {
      return;
    }

    var draggable = sender as UIElement;
    if (!ItemToItemHostMap.TryGetValue(draggable, out FrameworkElement draggableHost))
    {
      return;
    }

    Point newDragEndPosition = e.GetPosition(draggableHost);
    newDragEndPosition.Offset(-DragStartPosition.X, -DragStartPosition.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(draggable, newDragEndPosition.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(draggable, newDragEndPosition.Y);
  }

  private static void OnDraggablePreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    var draggable = sender as UIElement;       
    if (!ItemToItemHostMap.TryGetValue(draggable, out _))
    {
      if (!TryGetVisualParent(draggable, out Panel draggableHost))
      {
        return;
      }

      ItemToItemHostMap.Add(draggable, draggableHost);
    }

    DragStartPosition = e.GetPosition(draggable);
    draggable.CaptureMouse();
  }

  private static void OnDraggablePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    => (sender as UIElement)?.ReleaseMouseCapture();

  private static bool TryGetVisualParent<TParent>(DependencyObject element, out TParent parent) where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    parent = null;

    if (element is null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    if (element is TParent parentElement)
    {
      parent = parentElement;
      return true;
    }

    return TryGetVisualParent(element, out parent);
  }
}
```

### Usage example

**DataItem.cs**

```cs
class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Allow this item to change its coordinates aka get dragged
  private bool isPositionDynamic;
  public bool IsPositionDynamic 
  { 
    get => this.isPositionDynamic;
    set 
    {
      this.isPositionDynamic = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"
                Height="1000" 
                Width="1000">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
        <Ellipse Width="50"
                 Height="50"
                 Fill="Red"
                 Stroke="Black"
                 StrokeThickness="1" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                Background="Gray" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">

        <!-- If every item is draggable, simply set this property to 'True' -->
        <Setter Property="local:CanvasDragBehavior.IsDragEnabled"
                Value="{Binding IsPositionDynamic}" />

        <!-- Optional binding if you need the coordinates in the view model.
             This example assumes that the view model has a Top and Left property -->
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Again I got a lesson, I should have told more about whole app. The other features I need is create ellipse on left click, delete ellipse on right click, I'll definitelly implement `WeakEventManager` to avoid memory leaks after deleting element. One more question: what if don't want some canvas elements to be draggable? Create new attached property for each DataTemplate and check its value in CanvasDragBehavior?

Comment: That's not a problem. Your requirements are easy to realize without modifying much code. 1) Add and remove is realized by manipulating the collection that binds to the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl. In your case removing a EllipseVM will automatically remove it from the Canvas. This feature is already there and does not require any changes of the above example. 2) To make only particular elements draggable we can introduce an optional interface. Do you mean you have different types of objects of which some are draggable or do you have a single type of which only some instances are draggable?

Comment: I have updated the example. The idea is to add a `IsPositionDynamic` property to your data model (`EllipseVM`) and bind it to the attached property `CanvasDragBehavior.IsDragEnabled`. That's all. You can now control which elements are draggable by setting `IsPositionDynamic` on the model. If you have multiple dada types that are added to the ItemsControl, you can introduce a  e.g. `IPositionable` interface that has the `IsPositionDynamic` and other properties like `Position:Point` and `Top:double`, `Left:double` defined. Then let all items implement this interface.

Comment: The update is only related to the usage example. The behavior does not need any changes.

Comment: The other elements on my canvas will be `Image`, `Border` and 2 `lines`. All ellipses will be above the image and border. Image and Border must not be draggable. The whole app idea is to extract data from x-y chart where x-y chart is zoomable (`ScrollView`) like in AutoCAD. I already have the version that works but all logic is in code behind. So I'm trying to learn how to do it right.

Comment: Nice. This solution will help you to improve your code

Comment: As suggested, create the `IPrositionable` interface (see previous comment). Then create a data type for each individual canvas object type. This way you can create a DataTemplatre for each and display data as Image etc. Then  let every data type implement `IPositionable` and set the `IsPositionDynamic` property to control which elements can be dragged by the user. Then you have a pure MVVM solution where data and view is cleanly separated. As a bonus, the behavior is as generic as it can get. You can drag everything with it, no modifications needed..